# Можно ли сказать: "Решали по дизайну"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Мы устраняли последствия форс-мажоров и **решали по дизайну**.

Правильно ли построена фраза? Смущает "решали по дизайну" (имеется в виду "решали вопросы, связанные с дизайном данного помещения").

Comment: Если форс-мажоров несколько, то что тогда форс-мажор в принципе?

Comment: Одно из значений: непредсказуемое событие. Думаю, выражение "устраняли последствия форс-мажоров" приемлемо в разговорном стиле. Смысл: устраняли последствия таких событий, которые невозможно было предвидеть заранее.

Answer (score 2):

**Решать** - переходный глагол (решили задачу, вопрос и т. п. прямое дополнение), без прямого дополнения он употребляется перед инфинитивом (решили сделать и т. п.) или придаточным предложением (решили, что...). Поэтому "решать по" - просторечие, напоминающее полицейское выражение "нарушаете (без дополнений)". Можно заменить здесь глагол словами "**принимали решения** (по дизайну)" или "**решали вопросы** (дизайна)".

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "решать по" имеет право на существование, но в другом смысле: "решать в соответствии с".

**"Решали по дизайну" означает "решали, следуя дизайну".**

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Эту проблему нельзя **решать по** одному алгоритму, это штучная работа. [Вячеслав Игрунов, Дмитрий Камышев. Вячеслав Игрунов: денег у нас будет достаточно // «Коммерсантъ-Власть», 1999]

Поэтому городская власть предпочитает этот вопрос не решать вообще, чем **решать по** федеральному закону. [Ирина Бондаренко. Такая сложная жизнь (2002) // «Биржа плюс свой дом» (Н. Новгород), 2002.05.20]